# How to "remove all duplicates and original of duplicate" from a list of objects in Java 8?

Tags: list, lambda, java-8, set, comparator

I got two:

```
registryId:1
registryID:1
registryID:2
```

The final list should be: I mean remove 1 compeletly

```
registryID:2
```

I got this solution:

```
List<TerpAccountListV> terpAccountListVFinal = compareUpdate(terpAccountListV, xxedgeAccountsListV);

Set<TerpAccountListV> set = terpAccountListVFinal.stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet()<>(Comparator.comparing(TerpAccountListV::getRegistryId))));
```

But this will make a Single Set having registry ID.

How will i remove element from above List using this set in Java 8?

Comment: What about `.stream().distinct()`?

Comment: @VLAZ: No it keeps original element, like in example i explained that i need only 2 but 1 should go compeletly. Update question

Answer (score 1):

First, count the occurrence by `RegistryId` in list. Then create a set of a non-duplicate items' `RegistryId`

```
Set<Integer> set = 
        list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TerpAccountListV::getRegistryId,
                                           Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1L)
            .map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collector.toSet());
```

Then filter the list if `RegistryId` contains in set

```
List<TerpAccountListV> res =  list.stream()
                                  .filter(e -> set.contains(e.getRegistryId()))
                                  .collect(Collector.toList());
```

Update:
You can do set creation part this way also

```
Set<Integer> track = new HashSet<>();
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
for (Integer item : list) {
  if(!track.add(item.getRegistryId())) {
    set.remove(item.getRegistryId());
  } else {
    set.add(item.getRegistryId());
  }
}
```

Comment: For 10^5 I think it's work's  fine, though I added an iterative approach for set creation part using two set.